# Can't save changes to my profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I just tried editing my profile on www.stackoverflow.com and when I pressed save nothing happened, not even a notice appeared or a page reload. I tried clearing cache and still nothing happened.

Error log
[image]

Error location on page

[image]

Looks like someone forgot a `}` to close the `StackExchange.ready(function() {` function :p

Comment: Looking - possibly something I changed.

Comment: Have same problem.

Comment: What terrible browser is... oh, firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misplaced a `}` - it was supposed to be interpreted server side, but was interpreted as client side.

Fixed now - build is rolling out.